# Why am I getting an OSError (Errno 22) after about 2/3 of runtime in a loop writing to a file?

Tags: python

I have a script that is supposed to generate testdata for functions test in two of our databases. The function that is testet needs testdata in different sizes with 1 to > 10 million rows, string variable lengths from 8 charachters to >2GB. The smaller datasets generates fine with this script. But, when I try to create datasets with 10 millione row I get an Errno 22 after writing over 6 million rows (my last try did work all the way to row number 7 660 799)?

I've tried diefferent file extensions including regular *txt* with the same result. I haven't been able to check use of RAM in the machine running the script if that can be the issue?

My code looks like this:

```
import datetime, VarValues, re
from time import sleep
from os import getcwd, chdir
from random import randint

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
t1 = re.sub("[-:.]", "", str(t0)).replace(" ", "_")[0:15]

fn = input("File prefix: ")

chdir("H:/Project_DBDev/Python/Testdata")
i = 0
f = open(fn + "_" + t1 + ".txt2", "w")
f.write("Row\tLenght\tValue\n")

for j in range(VarValues.r):
    
    print("\n---\n" + str(j + 1) + "\n" + getcwd() + "\n")
    
    v = ""

    for i in range(randint(VarValues.rl,VarValues.rh)):

        ascii_value = randint(VarValues.al,VarValues.ah)
        v = v + chr(ascii_value)

    f.write(str(j + 1) + "\t" + str(len(v)) + "\t" + v + "\n")

    print("Value:\n" + v[0:9] + "...")
    print("\nLenght: " + str(len(v)) + "\n---\n")

f.close()

sleep(4)
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

print("\nRuntime " + str(int(round((t1 - t0).total_seconds(), 0))) + " seconds\n")
input()
```

And *VarValues* looks like this:

```
# Number of rows.
r = 10000000

# Lower random limit.
rl = 100

# Upper random limit.
rh = 1000

# Lowest ASCII.
al = 97

# Highest ASCII.
ah = 122
```

When running Errno 22 is adressed to row 27 (the `f.write(str(j + 1) + "\t" + str(len(v)) + "\t" + v + "\n")` statement.

I run Python 3.10.0

Don't now if it has any meaning but anyway, I'm coding in Visual Studio Code 1.54.3 in a Windows 10 environment with 16GB RAM.

Comment: Are you maybe on some crazy Windows FAT filesystem that only allows 2GB files or something like that?

Comment: Good question! I've checked all involved environments and disks and they're all running NTFS. Thanks anyway.